# Vertex painting smoothly

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-paint

anyone know if there's a way to avoid this while vertex painting?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be too increase our blead value in the options panel of painting. The only problem with that is you might have to move your uvs around a bit so they won't bleed into each other.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the only solution. Thanks :)